# Issue with an Update Query PhP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, insert-update

I have numerous error checkers which the newly inputted code successfully meet the requirements of, however, the data doesnt seem to be going into the database. Its not updating, therefore i believe theres something wrong with my line of update code

```
"UPDATE user (user_username, user_first, user_last, user_email) VALUES ('$uname', '$first', '$last', '$email');";
```

Basically want the new information typed in my input boxes to be inserted into the database

Comment: " the data doesnt seem to be going into the database". Are you sure you need to UPDATE and not INSERT ?

Comment: this is more of a INSERT pattern syntax. UPDATE is morelike: UPDATE users SET user_username = '$name', user_first = '$first', ....., WHERE user_id = '$user_id'... but this is only for example purposes. You should use prepared statements via mysqli or pdo since you code is outdated and very risky for sql injection attacks.

Comment: @NickZulu Ive included     $uid = $_SESSION['u_id']; at the top of my document and changed the update query to   $sql = "UPDATE user SET user_username = $uname, user_first = $first, user_last = $last, user_email = $email  WHERE user_id = '$uid'"; however its still not updating the information in the database, any idea why?

Comment: As always when you have these questions your first stop should be the [documentation on `UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html). You'll see the syntax you're using is not supported.

Comment: @BradArcher try $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET user_username = '".$uname."', user_first = '".$first."', user_last = '".$last."', user_email = '".$email."' WHERE user_id = '".$uid."'") or die (mysql_error()); but plz, even if it suits you, move on to newer code since this one is highly vulnerable

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Tim's answer, you should probably also use a prepared statement. The prepared statement will protect you from mysql injection, which could possibly destroy your database.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user (user_username, user_first, user_last, user_email) VALUES (:usr, :first, :last, :email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':usr', $uname);
$stmt->bindParam(':first', $first);
$stmt->bindParam(':last', $last);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: PDO's named placeholders are great because you can skip the `bindParam` part and just do `$stmt->execute(array('usr' => $uname, ...))` in one line.

Comment: @tadman good point, but its cool to show it in a really verbose manner to beginners.

Comment: Fair enough, but the "short" form is actually pretty self-explanatory and is what most people use in practice. `bindParam` is only really necessary if you have to override the type of the field.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the MySQL syntax for inserting a new row:

`INSERT INTO tblName (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (x, y, z);`

You have the `UPDATE` keyword instead.

Answer (score 0):

For inserting data you query will be

```
INSERT INTO user (user_username, user_first, user_last, user_email) 
VALUES ('$uname', '$first', '$last', '$email')
```

But if you want to UPDATE your data, you need use the UPDATE clause correctly.